# Create System.Xml.XmlDocument, not from string

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

It is possible to create a System.Xml.XmlDocument without initializing by parsing a string?
I want to create a XmlDocument representing the XML `<rootEl />`

I known the normal way to initialize an XmlDocument is by string-parsing as below:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<rootEl />");
```

However, is it possible to use the method outlined below?

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument("rootEl");
```

(I understand System.Xml.Linq seems to be more flexible, but right now I am stuck with oldschool.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not possible to do it with *exactly* the code you've given. There's no constructor for [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) which takes the content, either as a stream or as a string.

On the other hand, you could write:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("rootEl"));
```

Is that what you want? Please be more specific about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's done without a parsing a "whole" XML from string. Accepted!

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't do it the way you want.

Not sure if this is what you need, but you could do it like this:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
FileStream fs = new FileStream("whatever.xml", FileMode.Create);

XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fs);


writer.WriteRaw("<rootEl>");
writer.WriteRaw("<rootEl />");

writer.Flush();
fs.Close();
```

Comment: Not only can you do that (see Jon's answer), but your code will write invalid XML.